# Jframe dispose and mySQL connection relation

Tags: java, mysql, jframe, dispose

I am working on an application in JAVA. The user can interact with it threw various jframes windows that input data and get outputs from MySQL database. In various occasions the connection and the queries to the database are executed in the jframe constructors or some methods of them.
So my question is: Do I have to close the connection with the database before every individual jframe is disposed or is it happening automatically threw the dispose method?
If I do not close the connection what is the problem that might be erased?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database connections must be dispose as soon as possible, e.g., we must dispose them as soon as we know we will not reuse them again. Not closing database connections (like any other connection to other servers) that are not needed any more is consuming resources in the remote server (in your case database server). Those connections are limited and consume a certain amount of resources in the remote server that otherwise could be used to server other clients.

So bottom line, yes we should close database connection before closing the JFrame if we are not intending in reusing it in very near future (like for example in other alreay opened JFrame).

Answer (score 1):

You should always close your ResultSet, Statement and Connections, since they are managed by your DBMS, MySQL in your case. They can not be removed by Java Garbage collector like your JFrames.